# How to disable alignment in Qlabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a little C++ program using QT 5.8 framework.
It has a window with one label and I want to draw a sine wave in the label.

The sine wave should start at ten pixel from the left margin of the label but it is drawn according the alignment parameter of the label.

Is there any possibility to disable the alignment parameter of the label ?
Did you have similar problem and how do you fix it ?

Thank you very much for your help and cooperation
regards

This is my code:

```
#define SPAZIO_SX 10 // ten pixel from left
#define SPAZIO_BASSO 10 // ten pixel from bottom
void MainWindow::setGraphic()
{
  int i;
  QPicture pi;
  QPainter p(&pi);
  int x0,x1,y0,y1;
  int yCoord;
  yCoord=this->ui->GraphicLabel->geometry().height();

  p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  p.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 4, Qt::SolidLine,Qt::RoundCap,Qt::RoundJoin));
  x0=SPAZIO_SX;
  y0=yCoord-SPAZIO_BASSO-pvalMedia->getValue(0);  // return value(0-255)
  for(i=1;i<512;i=i++) {
      y1=yCoord-SPAZIO_BASSO-pvalMedia->getValue(i); 
      x1=x0+1;
      p.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
      y0=y1;
      x0=x1;
    }

  p.end(); //
  this->ui->GraphicLabel->setPicture(pi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation margin will do the job.

set QLabel margin with CSS, in order from `top`, `right`, `down`, `left` :

```
ui->label->setStyleSheet("margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;"); //10px left margin
```

or set margin all 4 sides:

```
ui->label->setStyleSheet("margin:10px;");
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem. Just an example: if the function is not a sine wave but a horizontal line at 30 pixels from bottom, it is vertically alligned (of course if the vertical alignment is AlignVCenter). How to display it at the righth position ?